# How to set max number of clients in sockjs connection

Tags: javascript, sockjs

I am currently experimenting with sockjs. How can I set the maximum number of clients that can join a sockjs server?

I understand that i can achieve this by simply closing any new connection if the total number of connections is above x, but i dont really find it elegant. I was hoping that there was some inbuilt way of doing this.

I am currently achieving this by:

> ```
> var numConnections = currentConnections.length;
> console.log('\nNumber of Connections = ' + numConnections);
> // check for number of connections
> if (numConnections >=3) {
>     //disconnect the client
>     conn.end();
>     }
> ```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you got resolved by the way ??

Answer (score 0):

As counter is very application based thing, especially in horizontally scaled environments with load balanced multiple SockJS servers - it is up to you to implement the mechanics of counting.

It is totally fine to have such minimalistic counter like you did. If you will have multiple services, you can easily switch to using redis for storing count of clients and share that value across different processes.

*My personal opinion - you should not worry about such simple things in early stages of development, and focus on real challenges and problems as they occur. Though is good to think, but experience will help you, just don't waste time on such little things.*